# Text got truncated for no reason in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this textfield in Rails, I entered this in edit:

> Lifts 09:00-00:45 mid-Jun-Aug (final
>   ascension to top 23:00, to other
>   levels 24:00), 09:30-23:45 Sep-mid-Jun
>   (final ascension to top 22:30, to
>   other levels 23:00), Stairs
>   09:00-00:30 mid-Jun-Aug (final
>   admittance 24:00), 09:30-18:30
>   Sep-mid-Jun (final admittance 18:00)

But then in show, it got truncated:

> Lifts 09:00-00:45 mid-Jun-Aug (final
>   ascension to top 23:00, to other
>   levels 24:00), 09:30-23:45 Sep-mid-Jun
>   (final ascension to top 22:30, to
>   other levels 23:00), Stairs
>   09:00-00:30 mid-Jun-Aug (final
>   admittance 24:00), 09:30-18:30
>   Sep-mid-Jun (final adm

When I go back to the edit again to check if it's still there, it got truncated. I tried other text, got truncated too. Is that character limit issue?

No special code in my Rails app to cause this. I just used `<%= sanitize @shop.operation_hours %>` only. Even if I turned off the `sanitize`, problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text has been truncated to 256 characters.

Assuming that this data is stored in a model object backed by a database, I strongly suspect this is due to the column lengths in your database. Standard 'string' fields often default to 256 characters long.

Try creating a migration that changes your column to a 'text' type instead:

```
class ChangeColumnToString < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :table_name, :attribute, :text
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :table_name, :attribute, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Got it. http://www.cowboycoded.com/2009/10/07/change-a-column-data-type-with-rails-migration/

Answer (score 0):

```
>> "Lifts 09:00-00:45 mid-Jun-Aug (final ascension to top 23:00, to other levels 24:00),
   09:30-23:45 Sep-mid-Jun (final ascension to top 22:30, to other levels 23:00),
   Stairs 09:00-00:30 mid-Jun-Aug (final admittance 24:00), 09:30-18:30 Sep-mid-Jun
   (final adm".length
=> 255
```

Seems you have created your `operation_hours` column with the type `string`, which resulted in `varchar(255)`. So when you save a long string into the db, it gets truncated. You need to get rid of this constraint (e.g., change the column type to `text`)